# Kusto - Custom Names for Rows fetched using IN condition

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to display custom names for the Row data fetched using IN condition in Kusto.

Below is the table structure-

[image]

Below is the query I've used-

```
customEvents
| project Action=customDimensions["ActionInvoked"]
| where Action in (
    "viewSelected",
    "myProjectsSelected",
    "watchlistSelected"
)
| summarize count() by tostring(Action) 
| sort by count_
| render columnchart
```

The output to the query is as below-

[image]

As noticed in the output **highlighted** column names ("viewSelected","myProjectsSelected" & "watchlistSelected") are being rendered as is.
These are not User friendly and I'd like to change it.
[image]

**NOTE:** I'm just a day old to Kusto, so my query might be bad. Please feel free to change it to a better one if needed.

Comment: I've answered your question. In the future, please post questions with minimal sample input in datatable format (as I did in my answer), to save time to those who want to help you :)

Comment: Sure @SlavikN will make a note of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to replace your original values in the Action column by the names you want to be displayed. The easiest way to do it is to use the [`case` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction) like this (look at the `| extend Action = case(...)` part):

```
customEvents
| project Action = tostring(customDimensions["ActionInvoked"])
| where Action in (
    "viewSelected",
    "myProjectsSelected",
    "watchlistSelected"
)
| extend Action = case(
    Action == "viewSelected", "Default Views",
    Action == "myProjectsSelected", "Custom Views",
    "Watchlist")
| summarize count() by Action
| sort by count_
| render columnchart
```

By the way, note that I moved the `tostring` higher up in the query, for convenience.

And here's how the new query works on your data:

```
datatable(Action:string) [
    "viewSelected",
    "myProjectsSelected",
    "watchlistSelected",
    "watchlistSelected",
    "viewSelected"
]
| extend Action = case(
    Action == "viewSelected", "Default Views",
    Action == "myProjectsSelected", "Custom Views",
    "Watchlist")
| summarize count() by Action
```

Output:

| Action | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| Default Views | 2 |
| Custom Views | 1 |
| Watchlist | 2 |

Comment: Thanks a ton @SlavikN this solution worked out perfect. :) :) Made my day